# exception occurs while saving XML using c#

Tags: c#, xml, ioexception

I am trying to update an existing XML file by adding a new child node using c#.
Everything is OK if I save it by new name but I want to update the same file and while doing it, got the following exception:

> System.IO.IOException:Process cannot access the file... because it is
>   being used by another process

Here is my code: (I am trying to add a new default node)

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string path = @"C:\Debug\default.xml";
doc.Load(path);
XmlNode NName = doc.CreateElement("default");

XmlNode SNO = doc.CreateElement("SNo");
SNO.InnerText = "2";
NName.AppendChild(SNO);

doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(NName);

doc.Save(path);
```

Also XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <default>
    <SNo>1</SNo>
  </default>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: **because it is being used by another process** this does not mean anything to you?

Comment: "because it is being used by another process" - well, [is it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)?

Comment: Make sure you haven't opened this xml file elsewhere (e.g. in browser to view it)

Comment: @david Yes, I know that the file is being used by the same process for creating the node, but how to solve this issue now?

Comment: It says that it used by another process so either you have opened it somewhere else apart from your current code.

Comment: tried reboot? I guess you are using Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the file is only being used by your process, then simply read it into a byte array, close the file, then save it again:
(I am using **.net 4.0** for this sample):

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 byte[] content = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
 using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(content))
 {
     doc.Load(memStream);
 }
 XmlNode NName = doc.CreateElement("default");

 XmlNode SNO = doc.CreateElement("SNo");
 SNO.InnerText = "2";
 NName.AppendChild(SNO);

 doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(NName);

 doc.Save(path);
```